# How to use a frame grabbed asynchronously with Vimba Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, camera, alliedvision, vimba-sdk

I am working with a system that uses an **Allied Vision Camera** with **Vimba Python**.

Currently, I grab frames synchronously inside a loop, convert them into numpy arrays and append those to a list.

```
for _ in range(10):
    frame = cam.get_frame()
    img = np.ndarray(buffer=frame._buffer, dtype=np.uint16, shape=(frame._frame.height, frame._frame.width))
    vTmpImg.append(img)
```

I need to optimize this process because it takes a significant amount of time. It would be ideal that the camera started streaming, taking frames and putting them in a queue or something and the I could retrieve them when I needed them. I figured that a good way to handle it is taking the frames **asynchronously**.

I've read the examples that Vimba has on [asynchronous_grab](https://github.com/alliedvision/VimbaPython/tree/master/Examples), but it is still not clear to me how can I grab the frames that the camera is taking.

Does anyone know how to approach it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What is unclear about the asynchronous grab? The code or the concept?
Maybe [asynchronous_grab_opencv.py](https://github.com/alliedvision/VimbaPython/blob/master/Examples/asynchronous_grab_opencv.py) is easier to modify. It transforms the frame into an OpenCV frame that can then be modified/saved etc in the Handler class. Basically, switch out the imshow command line for whatever you want to do with your frames.